# D3js json links search using 2 attributes

Tags: json, d3.js

so I have a page showing pathways between nodes with a json file like this:

```
{"nodes":[
    {"name":"Node 1", "Number":"01", "x":"48.23", "y":"638.54", "Status":"starting"},
    {"name":"Node 2", "Number":"02", "x":"129.05", "y":"658.49", "Status":"starting"},
    {"name":"Node 3", "Number":"03", "x":"174", "y":"687.79", "Status":"starting"},
    {"name":"Node 4", "Number":"04", "x":"169.96", "y":"626.92", "Status":"starting"},
    {"name":"Node 5", "Number":"05", "x":"263.65", "y":"631.47", "Status":"starting"}
],
"links":[
    {"source": 1, "target": 2, "value": 2},
    {"source": 1, "target": 3, "value": 8},
    {"source": 1, "target": 4, "value": 5},
    {"source": 2, "target": 3, "value": 4},
    {"source": 2, "target": 4, "value": 9}
]
}
```

At the moment I have it set up so that when ever I click on a node it shows all pathways to other nodes. What I want is another mode, where when I click on the node it only shows the pathway with the highest "value" attribute for that corresponding source value.

I have tried looking online for some d3js examples of something like this but haven't found anything and have no idea where to start.

atm I am using a d3.selectAll function to find all pathways for source 1 when i click on node 1 like this:

```
d3.selectAll(".from" + d.nodes[0].Number + ":not(.pathlabel)")
.transition()
.duration(10)
.style("stroke", "blue")
.style("display", "block")
.style("stroke-opacity", blueActive[d.nodes[0].Number])
;
```

My code is based on this example: http://bl.ocks.org/fhernand/9a9f93f2a6b0e83a9294

My code is on jsfiddle:
jsfiddle.net/jgs6d7fv

I just want to know how to search through my JSON file using d3.js to find a specific link based on the source and the value attributes.

Comment: I can help you out if you can put your solution till now on jsfiddle.

Comment: @Cyril, ok will do.
https://jsfiddle.net/jgs6d7fv/

Not too sure if I did that right, sorry, sort of new to this.

Comment: Ok your fiddle seems to be using some external sources and thus will never load.
Can you explain why show this path {"source": 1, "target": 3, "value": 8} is it because you want to show max for source =1 on clicking a node 1

Comment: @Cyril, I want to show this particular path because the value attribute represents the most popular path and I only want to show the most popular path for each node. So yes, when I click on node 1(source 1) I want it to only show the link that has source = 1, but has highest value.

In my actual json file I have about 60 different nodes, so I need to be able to do it dynamically.

Comment: @Cyril I just need to be able to search through the links in my JSON file and find the correct one, atm I don't know how to add a second term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the same example passed by you http://bl.ocks.org/fhernand/9a9f93f2a6b0e83a9294

This will get you all the list of link data **from**

```
d3.max(d3.selectAll(".from" + d.nodes[0].Number + ":not(.pathlabel)").data()
```

To get the maximum pass to a player you need to find the max pass **from** that is done like this

```
var from_max = d3.max(d3.selectAll(".from" + d.nodes[0].Number + ":not(.pathlabel)").data(), function (d) {
                return (d.value);
            });
```

To get the maximum pass to a player you need to find the max pass **to** that is done like this

```
//this will calculate the max for to

var to_max = d3.max(d3.selectAll(".to" + d.nodes[0].Number + ":not(.pathlabel)").data(), function (d) {
                return (d.value);
            });
```

Now you can display or hide the path on the basis of the max path thats done like this using the *display* css attribute:

```
d3.selectAll(".to" + d.nodes[0].Number + ":not(.pathlabel)")
                .transition()
                .duration(10)
                .style("stroke", "orange")
                .style("display", function (d) {
                if (d.value == to_max) {
                    return "block"
                } else {
                    return "none"
                }
            })
```

Working fiddle I have added comments [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/9ybtqr4L/1/).

Comment: Thanks so much! I will definitely be able to use this and take the relevant parts. You were very helpful. Thanks again!